# Xamarin: cannot add Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client reference

Tags: c#, android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin, nuget

while trying to develop simple Android App using Xamarin I came across a problem. Installing Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client through Nuget Package Manager gives following result:

```
Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client
5.2.3'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly 
references or content files that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
```

How can I solve this problem (with or without NuGet)?

**EDIT:**

Solution was to use Xamarin Studio to download this package into solution.

Comment: What would you like to achieve by having WebApi in your Android app? I kind of doubt that this is possible. WebApi was developed for servers not for mobile devices.

Comment: @Jakub Holovsky I need reference for HttpClientFactory, to connect with my existing Web Api

Comment: I use Xamarin Studio and I still have this problem.

Comment: llia, were you able to install it on Xamarin Studio ? I'm also having issues installing it.